# how place a RichTextField and a button in asingle line

Tags: blackberry

How can I place a RichTextField and a button in a single line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place them both in a [HorizontalFieldManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/HorizontalFieldManager.html).

Comment: In my app I already using a Horizontal field manager and adding listfield to it.When I add a textfield ans a button to it,I can see only a white screen

Comment: I'm sorry, you lost me. What does the listfiled has to do with the RichTextField and the button? Please give more details.

Comment: The listfield contains some texts from a webserver,when user click in these listfield items,the verticalfield mgr is reloaded with new listfields and so on.When I add RichTextField and button directly to the screen it seen in two different lines,I want it to be in a single line

Comment: don't add the RichTextField and the button directly to the screen. Place them in a HorizontalFieldManager and them add that HorizontalFieldManager to the screen.

Comment: Ok Mugur,I got the solution,I use a JustifiedVerticalFieldManager and add my fields to it,Thanks